# Laurent Series on the boundary

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $f(z)$ is analytic for $|z| \geq 1$, then it is analytic in $|z| >1$ and therefore has a Laurent series $f(z) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty c_n z^n,~\forall |z| > 1$. Is it also true that $f(z)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty c_n z^n$ on the boundary $|z|=1$?

Another related question is if $\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n z^{-n}$ is analytic on $|z| \geq 1$, is it true that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty |c_n| < \infty$?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

What exactly do you mean by "analytic on a closed set"? The most common convention is that it means "analytic on an open neighbourhood of the closed set".

If that's the case, $f$ is analytic on $|z| > r$ for some $r < 1$, and the answer to both your questions is yes: the Laurent series converges absolutely and uniformly on every $1 \le |z| \le R$.

Comment: mrf: It means that for every point on the unit circle, there exists a neighborhood in which the function is Holomorphic.

Comment: @jpv: In other words, holomorphic on a neighboorhood as I said. (Since $|z|=1$ is compact.)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** On the boundary $|z|=1$ if we let $z=e^{i\theta}$ then the series becomes

> $$ f(z) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} c_n e^{in\theta }. $$

Does this series reminds you about a well known series?

Comment: Mhenni: That may be the Fourier series but how can that information be used to answer the questions?

Comment: @jpv: This helps you to compute the coefficients of the power series of $f(z)$ on the boundary. Note that you are given that $f(z)$ is analytic on the boundary which means the it possess a power series.